# Deserialize in SObject in apex

Tags: apex, json

Hi I am trying to deserializing the json response and successfully parse the json response,Respone string look like :

> {"page":0,"itemCountPage":0,"itemCountTotal":0,"items":[{"id":2,"name":"Dell"},{"id":3,"name":"Riptech"}]}

```
public with sharing class PaginatedResultDO {
        public Integer page{get;set;}
        public Integer itemCountPage{get;set;}
        public Integer itemCountTotal{get;set;}
        public List<CustomerDO> items{get;set;}
    }

    public with sharing class CustomerDO {
       public Integer id {get;set;}
        public string name {get;set;}  
    }

JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(jsonStr);                 
PaginatedResultDO paginatedResult = (PaginatedResultDO)parser.readValueAs(PaginatedResultDO.class);    
system.debug('paginatedResult'+paginatedResult);
```

but if I do the same thing with below class then it's now allowing me and giving me error .In json response the items can be any list of object that's why I need SObject here

```
public with sharing class PaginatedResultDO {
        public Integer page{get;set;}
        public Integer itemCountPage{get;set;}
        public Integer itemCountTotal{get;set;}
        public List<SObject> items{get;set;}
    }
```

Comment: What is the error ?

Answer (score 3):

You can't instantiate an SObject, as it is abstract. You can only instantiate explicit subtypes, such as Account or MyCustomObject__c. Therefore, the JSON parser needs more details about what type of record it is (and Id, sadly, doesn't help the parser).

Therefore, you need to add an additional element called "attributes" that contains a named element "type" that specifies the type of SObject:

```
{
    "itemCountPage": 0,
    "itemCountTotal": 0,
    "items": [
        {
            "attributes": {
                "type": "Account"
            },
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Dell"
        },
        {
            "attributes": {
                "type": "Account"
            },
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Riptech"
        }
    ],
    "page": 0
}
```